# How can I get the data of variable from a function to another function in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm  trying to get the data of a $path from a function to another function so I can update the table of my database by using the $path from another function

```
function upload_image($table, $image)
{
    global $path;
    $path = 'complaints/'.date("d-m-Y").'-'.time().'-'.rand(10000, 100000) . '.jpg';
    if(file_put_contents($path, 
        base64_decode($_POST['image']))){
        $this->sql = "insert into complaints (path) values ('".$path."')";
        if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}

function complaints($table, $complaints)
{
    $complaints = $this->prepareData($complaints);
    $this->sql =
        "UPDATE " . $table . " SET user_complaints = '".$complaints."' WHERE path = '".$path."' ";
    if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

I tried to use global method but I still get an undefined variable error

Comment: can't you call the complaints to function inside the upload_image function?

Comment: or you can define $path outside the function as global var, as I see right now you are defining the var inside the upload_image function

Comment: You are using `$this` variables, if these methods are inside a class, you can create member variables. e.g. Declare at top of class: `'private $path = ''`, then set variable `$this->path = 'complaints/...'`, then you can access in any method with `$this->path`

Comment: $this->path works but the update function didn't update anything in my database

Comment: it looks like $this-path in update sql query gets null when I use it

Comment: (Aside: Global variables are considered as bad design.) The `$path` variable is not declared global in your `complaints` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class, you can create a `path` member, like this:

```
protected $path = null;

protected function getPath() {
    return $this->path;
}

protected function setPath($thePath) {
    $this->path = $thePath;
    return $this;
}
```

and, instead of using the `global $path`, whenever you want to get the value, you just call `$this->getPath()` and whenever you want to set the value, just call `setPath`, like

```
$this->setPath('complaints/'.date("d-m-Y").'-'.time().'-'.rand(10000, 100000) . '.jpg');
```

Yet, you have another problem as well. You insert the `path` into your `complaints` table, whereas in your `complaints` function you have a `$table` parameter and you have this query:

```
"UPDATE " . $table . " SET user_complaints = '".$complaints."' WHERE path = '".$path."' ";
```

I'm not sure what `$table` is, but, if it's not the `complaints` table, then you might also be missing a record in your `$table` that has the `path` of the path you have specified. So, you might need to insert some other records as well.